# Not able to write to an exisitng file in Flutter

Tags: flutter, csv, dart

I am trying to overwrite the contents of a CSV file in my `app_name/assets/file.csv` path. I'm using [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) and [csv](https://pub.dev/packages/csv) for these operations.

Here's the code that is supposed to write to the existing CSV file:

```
updateQuantity(customer, index, qty, list) async {
    list[index][2] = qty;
    String updatedCsv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(list);
    print(updatedCsv);

    final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = "${dir.path}/assets/$customer.csv";

    File file = await File(path);
    file.writeAsString(updatedCsv);
  }
```

The error I receive:

```
E/flutter ( 4352): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/data/user/0/com.example.data_collection_2/app_flutter/assets/Test.csv' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

I have scoured the internet but nothing seems to be helping me write to the file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the directory `assets` already exists? If the CSV does not already exist then it will fail since the directory `assets` probably does not exist either.

The way to fix this is to do `File file = await File(path).create(recursive: true);`.

This will create the file and the directory `assets` if they do not already exist. If they do exist it will do nothing and will not fail so it is safe either way.